# Why can't I have a numeric value as the ID of an element?

Tags: html, standards, web-standards

Working on a project, nearly finished and just tidying up the HTML and I find out that you're not really allowed to have an ID that is just a number-

> < a> attribute "id" has invalid value "567" The attribute ID is of type ID. As described  above, it should begin with a letter and have no spaces

```
Good    <a id="567" href="/index.html">
Good    <a id="n567" href="/index.html">
```

I can go through my code and add a letter then strip it when the value is used in my jQuery but it would be messing around I don't really need.

Is there a reason I shouldn't be using numbers as ID's?

Comment: These answers remind me of parenting:  *"But why can't I...?"* --  *"because I **SAID so**!"*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That's just what the spec says.

From the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The good news is that the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is more lenient:

> The `id` attribute specifies its element's **unique identifier (ID)**.
>   The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

Comment: First time HTML5 has come in handy for me! Still no real reason why HTML4 doesn't like it but I'm glad I'm not doing anything wrong.

Comment: I used numeric IDs since 2002 and no browser ever failed to work with them properly. I think such spec is as good as useless and can be safely disregarded.

Answer (score 15):

> Why can't I have a numeric value as the ID of an element?

Because [that's what the HTML4 spec dictates](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

---

On the other hand, [the HTML5 spec has removed this requirement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).