# jQuery Selector of a particular class inside a particular id

Tags: jquery

I would like to append HTML into a  div of a particular ID there .How do i select it ?

```
<div id="1">
 <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>  


<div id="2">
 <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"> TO APPEND INSIDE THIS DIV </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>  

<div id="3">
 <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

i was using

```
 $(data).appendTo("#"+id).find(".c");
```

but its giving me problem as the appending is not going inside the div but outside the div

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try,

```
$('div#3 div.c').eq(1).append('<div class="new">NEW</div>');
```

or

```
$('<div class="new">NEW</div>').appendTo($('div#4 .c:eq(1)'));
```

You can try:

```
$(data).appendTo($('#'+ id +' .c'));
```

For more specificity may use index of any specific `div.c`;

```
$(data).appendTo($('#'+ id +' .c:eq(2)')); // append to third `div.c`
```

**UPDATE:** for `appendTo()` just wrapped the target selector with `$()` and it works for me.

**NOTE** DON'T USE ONLY NUMERIC ID. IT ID PROHIBITED. FOR MORE [READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element)

Comment: @AdiMathur I have shared a link in my answer, read that. the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: i was using 
 $(data).appendTo("#"+id).find(".c");

but its giving me problem as the appending is not going inside the div but outside the div

Comment: Doesnt this mean ... Append to the ( ID which also has a class .c ) ?

Comment: @AdiMathur See my last update answer, you have to wrap the target with `$()` for `appendTo()`.

Comment: mine wasnt working because there awsnt a space in " .c" . Space is need ? it stated working after giving a space

Comment: @AdiMathur space is needed, because `.c` is child is of `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and Space target to child element

Answer (score 2):

ID attributes cannot start with a number. If you change your id attribute to something like `item-2`, then you can use the following:

```
var html = '<div></div>';
$('#item-2 .c:eq(1)').append(html);
```

Comment: i was using 
 $(data).appendTo("#"+id).find(".c");

but its giving me problem as the appending is not going inside the div but outside the div

Comment: That honestly doesn't make a lot of sense. `.append()` will add the html to the end of any matching elements. In your case, you should have 3 matching elements, because you have 3 elements with class `c` (within the element with the specified id). Given that you only wanted to append to the second item, I recommended `.c:eq(1)`. So, `$(data).appendTo('#' + id).find('.c:eq(1)')` should work. Perhaps you can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if that's still not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

This work.

```
$('#2 .c:eq(1)').html("<p>Hello</p>");
```

---

Edit:

```
​$('<p>Hello!</p>').appendTo($('#2 .c:eq(1)'));​
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/yfxXj/)**

Comment: i was using 
 $(data).appendTo("#"+id).find(".c");

but its giving me problem as the appending is not going inside the div but outside the div

Comment: then, do that: ​$(data).appendTo($('#2 .c:eq(1)'));​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#2 .c').html('<p>Stuff, junk, crud</p>');
```