# Jquery hide() all elements with certain class except one with certain parent

Tags: jquery, css

My question is similar to this one: [Jquery hide() all elements with certain class except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612379/jquery-hide-all-elements-with-certain-class-except-one). However in my case I have a certain parent.

I tried:

```
$('.slideNum').hide();
$('#marginRight ul li.selBar.slideNum').show();
```

The `slideNum` that has `selBar` as parent shouldn't be hidden, but it does!

Unlike the popular answer I didn't use "not" because the condition is for the parent and not for the element itself.

Comment: Why didn't you use the `.not()` method or a filter, and what is your HTML? Obviously without a HTML sample we cannot know if you wrote your selectors correctly.

Comment: @roko I said why in the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not()` by using the parent as part of selector to filter out

```js
$('.slideNum').not('.selBar *').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideNum">Should be hidden</div>
<div class="selBar">
  <div class="slideNum">Should be visible</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function in the not filter (https://api.jquery.com/not/)
like this:

```
   $('.slideNum').not(function () {
        return $(this).parent(".selBar").length !== 0;
    }).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, however had a mistake that I corrected.