# Using jQuery load method to load new content to a li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am having some difficulty using the load method to load new content to a li element. When i try to use this the new content prepends to the element, that is gets added to the top instead of replacing the current content. Here is the element layout

```
             <!-- List The News Items mainPage.php-->
                        <li id="news_list"> 

                            <?php include 'libs/file.php';?>
                         </li>

           //pagination links
          for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
            { 
                echo '<li id="'.$i.'"><a href="#" >'.$i.'</a></li>';


                  }
```

and the js function

```
            //js function
            //Pagination Click
     $(".paging li").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#news_list").val("");
      //Loading Data
      var pageNum = $(this).attr("id");
     $("#news_list").load("file.php?news_page=" + pageNum);
      $(this).children("a").setClass("active");


});
```

This is a part of a pagination script I am building. Also the following line

```
              $(this).children("a").setClass("active");
```

Does not apply the class to the nested 'a' element within the selected li. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Name of the method is `addClass` not `setClass`.

Comment: ID's aren't supposed to be entirely numeric. Give your li IDs an alphabetic prefix.

Comment: noted, will try something right now, thanks much for the fast reply

Comment: @Asad There's nothing in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute, which supports your claim.

Comment: You probably got an error, and it probably says that `addClass` is not a function. Check your console

Comment: @OlafDietsche You're looking at the new spec. Try looking at HTML4: "ID and NAME tokens **must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])**"

Comment: sadly missed the addClass >_<, but the main problem is still there

Comment: Asad is right here is about [Valid Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element)

Comment: @Asad You're right, found it at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name