# Why does it matter the order variables are concatenated in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, concatenation

So, I'm working with a page that displays some links to specific people pages. I'm using a hyperlink to submit my forms. I have this code in a loop and am using the integer `$position` to give different `id`s to the multiple forms on the page.

Why does this work:

```
<form id="<? echo "Form" . $position;?>" method="post" action="../lecture">
<input type="hidden" name="personID" value="<? echo $indexstr;?>">
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="<? echo "Form" . $position ;?>.submit()"  ><? echo $firstname. ' ' . $lastname;?></a>
```

and this doesn't:

```
<form id="<? echo $position . "Form";?>" method="post" action="../lecture">
<input type="hidden" name="personID" value="<? echo $indexstr;?>">
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="<? echo $position . "Form" ;?>.submit()"  ><? echo $firstname. ' ' .   $lastname;?></a>
```

In case there was a problem with types and `$position` being an integer, I even tried converting it to a string before concatenating using `strval()`. The only difference is the order in which I concatenate "*Form*" and `$position`.

I really just want to understand. Thank you in advance for any responses I get.

Comment: You don't have to indicate edits in the post itself.  A complete edit history of the post is available to everyone here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14655760/revisions.  Your initial edit was within the 5 minute grace period, so it wasn't logged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ID cannot start with a numeric character

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Dang is that really it? D: *facepalm* Is there a reason why it's not allowed?

Comment: Probably because the language spec says so.  In most languages, a numeric digit indicates the start of a numeric literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: Added link to specification from answer noted by popnoodles

Comment: Note that the HTML spec doesn't necessarily affect the ecmascript spec and vice versa. As of HTML5, ID attribute values *can* start with a number: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class The issue is strictly with the javascript I presume.

Comment: Well thanks for your help guys. I would never have thought of that. I just assumed the naming conventions for the ID were the same as a regular variable. Definitely won't do that again..