# How do you disable a button using an onclick javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove button click event after press.
How can I edit the function so whenever it's clicked, it gets disabled then runs the url, or vise-versa.

```
<form id="edit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button" onclick="this.value='test...'; MyFunction();" id="1" class="button blue" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    function MyFunction() {
        var url = "editing.php";
        document.getElementById("edit").setAttribute('action', url);
        return false;
    }
    $(".blue").click(function(){
        $(".blue").removeClass("disabled");
        $(this).addClass("disabled");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `onclick`, and do it the proper way :

```
<form id="edit" action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="a1" class="button blue" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#a1').on('click', function() {
        $(this).val('test...').prop('disabled', true);
        $("#edit").attr('action', 'editing.php');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".blue").click(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: `prop()` should be used here instead of `attr()`. See: [prop vs attr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/254830). For changing state, prop is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `disabled` attribute

```
$('.blue').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd6u8/10/)

---

As @doppelgreener pointed out, [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is equally valid here

```
$('.blue').prop('disabled', true);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd6u8/9/)

Comment: `prop()` should be used here instead of `attr()`. See: [prop vs attr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/254830). For changing state, prop is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily through jQuery using the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$('.blue').click(function() {  
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

By the way, I noticed that you're using jQuery. Why not 'jQuery-ify' your whole code:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var url = "editing.php";
    $("#edit").attr('action', url);
    return false;
}

$(".blue").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("disabled").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the `.blue` button **clickable only once**. The `.one()` method of jQuery is just the thing for you. Here is the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

```
$("#edit > .blue").one("click", function() {
    //Code here will only run once.
});
```

> *"How can I edit the function so whenever it's clicked, it gets disabled then runs the url, or vise-versa."*

I think you want the form to be submitted only once here; so:

```
<form id="edit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button" class="button blue" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    //To make the form SUBMITTABLE ONLY ONCE:
    $("#edit").one("submit", function() { 
        $(".blue").prop("disabled", true); //you can still set the button disabled if you like
        $('#edit').attr('action', "editing.php"); //setting the action attribute here
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what your `DOCTYPE` is but if it's HTML4; you cannot have numeric ID for an HTML element. HTML5 seems to allow that. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987693/112731).

[**Demo Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/cDcux/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="button" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')"/>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Element IDs cannot begin with a number ;)