# Jquery/CSS/HTML- Sliding highlight menu with the HTML I already have

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have this HTML:

```
 <nav>
        <div id="nav-show">
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Home</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">About</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Projects</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Quality</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Products</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Contact Us</a>
            <a class="m-btn rnd black mobile-hide" href="">Links</a>
        </div>
```

How could I possibly implement something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/)? (I am a JS noob)

As the article says:

*The Idea*

*The idea is to have a highlight of some kind (a background or an underline) follow you around as you mouse over the different links in the navigation. This will happen with jQuery and it's animation abilities. As such, the "magic line" will only be appended via JavaScript. Once added to the list and styled, as you mouse over the different links, it figures out the left positioning and the width and animates to match*

I don't really want to change the HTML due to various factors.

I have jQuery etc, it would need to be compatibe with IE8 up.

**I did try this: [Code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swhgu)**

Harley

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? I am tired of typing this again and again

Comment: The tutorial is there, have you tried implementing the code from the tutorial, you'd obviously need to tweak it to suit your markup..

Comment: Rather than asking people to do the work for you, why don't you read through the tutorial and try to implement it yourself. You might learn something.

Comment: @Karna Tried shoehorning the script to work with what I already had. Didn't work. Googled it before asking question, as always! :)

Comment: @harley post whatever you have tried, try setting it up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @harley: Show us what have you tried. Some piece of code. and what didnt work. (Stackoverflow works this way only)

Comment: @badZoke This is what I was doing [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swhgu](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swhgu)

Comment: Perfect :) That should shut us all up :D

Comment: @harley fixed your code, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a bit of tweaking,

The problem with the code you were implementing was mainly trivial errors,

Your markup has `id="nav-show"`, but your js was using `$(".nav-show")`.

Syntax errors with they way you were declaring variables, best practice (for small js), define each new variable on a different line,

```
var $el;
var leftPos;
var newWidth;
var $mainNav = $("#nav-show");
```

A logical error with the way width was being calculated for the `#magic-line`, so,

This

```
newWidth = $el.parent().width();
```

Gets replaced with

```
newWidth = $el.width();
```

[test link](http://jsfiddle.net/qdu7f/7/)

Comment: I changed `$(".nav-show")`, shortly afterwards... (Or so I thought) I'll look at the jsFiddle and then probably accept your answer :) Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

well u can do this with the help of css also

```
    .menu {
        position:fixed;
        top:142px;
        right:36px;
        float:right;
        height:50px;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 0px #FFFFFF;
        background-image:url(../img/m3nuta8.png);
        }        
    .menu ul {
            margin:0px;
            padding:1px 1px 0px 1px;
            }
        .menu ul li {
            float: left;
            display:inline;
            padding:0px;
            border-right:thick #FFF;
            margin:0px;
            height:48px;
            }
        .menu ul li:hover {
            background-color:#3F3;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
            }
        .menu ul li:first-child:hover {
            border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
            border-top-left-radius:10px;
            }
        .menu ul li:last-child:hover {
            border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
            border-top-right-radius:10px;
            }
        .menu ul li a {
            margin:inherit;
            alignment-adjust:central;
            float:right;
            font-family:Kreon, sans-serif;
            font-size:20px;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:12px 15px 10px 15px;
            text-shadow:2px 2px 3px #000000;
            height:40px;
            }
```

and this is the html code :

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me? Thanks anyway

Comment: ids and classes can't start with numbers

Comment: @Pete Just curious, why not? Will classs/id's that start with numbers not actally work, or is it just good practice?

Comment: u should atlest try @harley

Comment: @harley they won't work

Comment: @Codehunter Too lazy :) OK, I did, and `color:red;` had no effect. Why though?? What practical impact can a number have as opposed to a letter?

Comment: @harley it was just a mistake as Pete said they wont work

Comment: Apparently in html5 you may be able to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: @Peta thanks for the link :) ancidently i wrote that few days back ,actually i was planing something like `active` class for it