# Delete part of numeric id of divs

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly I added the numeric id to most of my div `class="line"`

```
var adder = document.getElementsByClassName("line");             
for(var i = 0 ;i<adder.length;i++){         
    adder[i].id=i;
}
```

How to remove the divs which id is larger than, for an exaple, 10?

I fell into trouble when using parameter as the id in JS. It seems that it's illegal to write like this `document.getElementsById(i);`

PS: Is that appropriate to set id as pure Arabic numbers?

Comment: *" It seems that it's illegal to write like this `document.getElementsByClassName(i)`"* You are setting the **ID** to `i`, not the **class**. It's not illegal to write such code, but if there is no element with *class* `i`, it will return an empty list. As for your question, you select the elements by class again (`.getElementsByClassName("line")`, iterate over the elements (like you already do) and compare the element's ID against `10`.

Comment: @Felix Kling sorry I copied code and forgot to make modification...

Comment: document.getElementById(i.toString())

Comment: This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x2cMj/. It's quite the same no ?

Comment: And about pure number IDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing what you are trying to do is not add ids above the number 10? If that's the case then why  not just do:

```
var adder = document.getElementsByClassName("line");             
for(var i = 0 ;i<10;i++){         
    adder[i].id=i;
}
```

If you want to do this as a seperate operation for some reason then:

```
var adder = document.getElementsByClassName("line");             
for(var elem in addr){         
    if(parseInt(addr[elem].Id) > 10){
       element = document.getElementById(addr[elem].Id);
       element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: @hazzik Unfortunately it's not. For(each) loops work different in javascript.

Comment: @hazzik Alright my dear friend. Here's a fiddle with your suggestion (only elem instead of addr[elem])

http://jsfiddle.net/VC95x/2/

and here is one with my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/KzdJN/3/

You can see for yourself which one works. I suggest you read the answer once more. The first bit of code is to suggest that there is a way to NOT have ids above 10 at all. The second bit of code is for when you have added ids above 10 and now want to remove them.

PS. I know about the uppercase in 'Id'. I was typing on a mobile device and I think that is something that the OP could easily figure out

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yxCEb/

It's

```
adder.item(i);
```