# adding specific type of code

Tags: javascript, html, charts

it's me again, and I found something, but something I missing. I want to get value from id and I can't do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var chart;
        var legend;

        var chartData = [{
            name: "NPukelis",
    **value: document.getElementById("2").innerHTML;**
        }, ....
```

`<td id="2" >19</td>`  **I want to get number from this one**

Comment: Don't use a number for an id.

Comment: Ok but i think that line **value: document.getElementById("2").innerHTML;** is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Why can't I have a numeric value as the ID of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element)

Change your id to a proper valid id.
Assigning numeric id does not give your an error,but still is not a good practice.You will keep looking for error and it will bug all of your time.

Try this instead

```
 <td id="item2" >19</td>

document.getElementById("item2").innerHTML
```

Comment: Ok but i think that line value: document.getElementById("2").innerHTML; is not correct.

Comment: it is perfectly correct...what are you doing ...try console..what error are you getting??

Comment: where i should try it? i am absolutely new. When I'am trying to get values from table with this getElementById my chart not shows on screen.

Comment: i would suggest you to go step by step...dont create a array which has an object inside it,then you access it.. `var chartData = [{a:1,b:1}]`...instead store the values directly..`var value=document.getElementById("item2").innerHTML`;

Answer (score 0):

I briefly ran into an issue myself trying to reproduce your problem - the issue being that I didn't have `<table>` tags around the `<td>` field, at which point the field simply wasn't recognized and I could not get its contents by ID.  But as you can see at the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eup3y/3/ using a number for the ID, whilst not recommended, is not the problem (if you are using HTML5 - for older browsers that's not true as the spec required the ID to start with a letter).

In order to debug, I recommend that you break this into smaller pieces (that usually is a good idea):

- Can you access the value from a "regular" script - use for example

  `alert(document.getElementById("2").innerHTML);`

If you can't, then make sure that you have valid HTML in the region around your table. In particular make sure there are opening and closing `<table>` tags around it. If the HTML didn't parse correctly, you can't extract the elements by `ID`

- Can you create the chart element that you want when you hard code the value (instead of looking up the value `19` as you are doing now)

My hunch is that your HTML doesn't parse properly. If you open the page with an error console open, you will find the error quickly I imagine.