# Multiple delete when given an array of ids using sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an array of ids such as [1,2,3,4]. And i like to delete all the instance in a single go.

I tried to use bulkDelete of sequelize.js but it throws an error showing bulkDelete not a method.
If i use destroy method of sequelize then only single entity is removed or deleted.
While looping the delete clause it deletes the entry but the server stops.

Comment: Do you want to delete the DOM elements the IDs represent, or just the elements in the array?

Comment: are these ids are DOM element Ids?

Comment: @jerin:check the answer,its pretty simple..

Answer (score -1):

1. If possible,avoid id with numerical value.[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element)
2. `myArray=[]; or myarray.length=0 //this will refresh your array!!`

Assign your array with any one of the bove suggestion and your array with content will loose all its content.

Comment: There's no reason not to use numerical values as IDs, at least not since HTML5 -- and even HTML 4 browsers typically handled it fine.

Comment: are you sure its DOM ids?

Answer (score -1):

Try to reintialize your array to empty as myArray=[];