# Change div to class active only when needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get each title/block bar of my little carousel controls to change to blue when 'active' and showing its content. Right now they will keep switching between blue and black when clicked, this is pretty much just be testing things out but overall is there anyone which may be able to amend my javascript to control the active/non active state of each button to do this.

I've left a live url to have a look so you can see and some code:

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1bijza0  (Homepage, next to the large image.)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="index-controls">
    <li><div id="1" class="active">FREE DISC Profile</div>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>Training that fits like a glove</h2></li>
            <li><p>Your company is as individual as the people it employs; and as such, it’s likely that your training requirements don’t tick any one, particular box. You may currently have a personnel issue that requires urgent attention. Or, you are taking a serious look at the management strategies you use to run your organisation and are considering an overhaul.</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div id="2">Last Minute Availability</div>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>Training that fits like a glove</h2></li>
            <li><p>Your company is as individual as the people it employs; and as such, it’s likely that your training requirements don’t tick any one, particular box. You may currently have a personnel issue that requires urgent attention. Or, you are taking a serious look at the management strategies you use to run your organisation and are considering an overhaul.</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div id="3">Bespoke Training</div>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>Training that fits like a glove</h2></li>
            <li><p>Your company is as individual as the people it employs; and as such, it’s likely that your training requirements don’t tick any one, particular box. You may currently have a personnel issue that requires urgent attention. Or, you are taking a serious look at the management strategies you use to run your organisation and are considering an overhaul.</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('#1').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
jQuery('#2').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
jQuery('#3').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#index-controls div { display: block; background-color: #222424; font-weight: bold; margin: 0px; cursor: pointer; padding: 19px 20px 20px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #4e92ad; color: #fff; font-size: 1.1em; }
#index-controls .active { background-color: #4e92ad; }
#index-controls ul { padding-left: 0; margin-top: 0; }
#index-controls ul{ display: none; background-color: transparent; padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px; }
#index-controls ul li { list-style-type: none; background-color: transparent; width: 240px; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; }
```

Comment: take the content in <a href="">bbf</a> a nd you can use a:active{ color:red } for the  this

Comment: I think toggleClass is deprecated in the last jQuery

Comment: @JonasGrumann No mention of deprecation on the docs page: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: sorry got confused with http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use a number for your id, and don't use a number as the first letter of an id.

Secondly, don't use id's for the jquery part of this.

Give all those divs the same class, such as `class="same-class"`

like this:

```
<div id="one" class="active same-class">FREE DISC Profile</div>

<div id="two" class="same-class">Last Minute Availability</div>

<div id="three" class="same-class">Bespoke Training</div>
```

And then for your jquery do this.

```
jQuery('.same-class').click(function(){
  jQuery('.same-class').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

So whenever you click on an element that has `class="same-class"` , it will remove any `active` class from any of the elements with `same-class`, but then it will add the class `active` to the one you clicked on.

So this will work for all three of those div's, as well as if you added a thousand more divs with that same class.

EDIT : Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/az4c3/

Comment: As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element you can use numeric ids in HTML5 (wanted to point that out aswell, but did a little research first)

Comment: @Merguez Yes, I'm aware. But it's still bad practice in my opinion. There are other things like data- attributes in html 5 which would be a lot better suited for numbers in my opinion.

Comment: True, I'ld agree with the bad practice argument.

Comment: Whilst the other response also worked, I really appreciate the constent improvements to your answer and just help so quickly. Thank you. And all others who answered. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you could just do that:

```
jQuery('#1,#2,#3').click(function(){
  jQuery('#1,#2,#3').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Keep in mind, that this is no flexible solution and you want to keep your code reusable. So in the long run you want to work with classes rather than id's to keep your code flexible. There is also one unnecessary "search-query" in the above code. A refactored, much nice approach would be something like:

```
var $clickables = $('.clickable');
$clickables.click(function(){
  $clickables.removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This will make your code scale with the number of `.clickable` elements you add, if you once want to extend your accordion to a 4th or 5th element.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
jQuery("#input-controls div").click(function() {
    jQuery("#input-controls div.active").add(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle that is very flexible:

http://jsfiddle.net/8VxLw/1/

```
var list = jQuery('#index-controls li div');
list.click(function() {
    list.removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```