# append id link to an element in a facebox window

Tags: jquery

I have a link with an id 1, when clicked a facebox popup window appears, and in the popup there is select element, I would like to add the same link id to the select element of the popup

i want to append the link id to the select element inside the popup window.

link

```
<a class="browse" href="some link" id="1">browse</a>
```

popup window

```
<div id="facebox"
<div class="popup">

<div align="center">   
 <form name="keys">

   <select class="browse_window" name="keyvalue" size="20">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</form>'
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some example HTML or a fiddle here. I was going to post a one line solution (to keep you happy) and vote to close, but I'm not even sure what your parameters are here.

Comment: "I have a link with an id 1"
Please, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: not what I am looking for, I am just looking  on how to append an id of clicked link to an element inside a popup window.