# jQuery remove too many fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form where the user can add fields one after the other. For each field I am setting a "remove" button. Each field is in a table, so I give a random id to the table, and pass this id to a removing function doing: `$(random-id).remove()`.

The strange thing is that jQuery is removing all of the tables created by the user, as if the id is not taken into account

Why that can be?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>

        function delete_field(id)
        {
            $("#"+id+"").remove();
        }

        function add_form_field()
        {
            id = Math.random();
            html = '<table id='+id+'>\
                        <tr><td>Label           </td></tr>\
                    </table>\
                    \
                    <button onclick=delete_field('+id+')>remove</button>';

            $("form").append(html);
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        </form>
        <button onclick=add_form_field()>   Add a field </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you get id from?

Comment: The `<button>`s will by default `submit` the `<form>`, causing navigation and, in this case, reloading the page without any `<table>`s. Add `type="button"` to them to change their behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: @TobyAllen you beat me to the punch.. That was my question exactly

Comment: @jonatah : how am i suppose to do the "type=button" trick ?

Comment: @user3318273 The `type` [is an attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) you can add within the `html` string -- `<button type="button" onclick=...>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use Math.random, rather increment a number and create ID like: `#tab_NN`.
- **Add an ID to your Form Element** `id=myForm`
- Delegate click events to dynamically generated *delete* buttons using `.on()`
- While removing the table that matched the button `data-*` attribute, delete the button too using `.add( this )` (where `this` stays for the clicked button)

```js
var id = 0;

function delete_field(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#tab_"+ $(this).data("remove")).add(this).remove();
}

function add_form_field(){
  id += 1;
  var html = '<table id="tab_'+ id +'">'+
      '<tr><td>Label</td></tr>'+
      '</table>'+
      '<button data-remove="'+id+'" class="remove">remove</button>';

  $("#myForm").append(html);
}

$('#addField').on('click', add_form_field);
$('#myForm').on('click', '.remove', delete_field);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm"></form>
 <button id="addField">   Add a field </button>
```

The code above allows you to have changes in the future markup cause it targets a specific ID, but *in case your DELETE buttons will always be exactly after `table`* than you can do it without assigning ID's, by simply using `.prev("table")`:

http://jsbin.com/wuqati/1/edit

```
function delete_field(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev("table").add(this).remove();
}

function add_form_field(){
  var html = '<table>'+
      '<tr><td>Label</td></tr>'+
      '</table>'+
      '<button class="remove">remove</button>';

  $("#myForm").append(html);
}

$('#addField').on('click', add_form_field);
$('#myForm').on('click', '.remove', delete_field);
```

Comment: There are some minors mistakes in the code but globally it gee me the good way to made the work :)

Comment: @user3318273 :) glad it did!

Comment: But how can I catch an onclick event on a submit button now ?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` produces a floating point number less than 1 which is invalid for an `id`. You can use a global variable to keep count of the rows created. Keep in mind that a `CSS ID` can not start with a digit. So append the number to a string before using it as an ID.

```
<script>

        function delete_field(id)
        {
            $("#"+id+"").remove();
        }
        tableID = 1;
        function add_form_field()
        {
            id = 'table-'+tableID;
            html = '<table id='+id+'>\
                        <tr><td>Label           </td></tr>\
                    </table>\
                    \
                    <button onclick=delete_field('+id+')>remove</button>';

            $("form").append(html);
            tableID++;
        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify this by doing something like below.

```js
$(".remover").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="input One"/> <input type="button" class="remover" value="remove" />
        </td> </tr>
    
  <tr>
       <td> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="input Two"/> <input type="button" class="remover" value="remove" />
        </td> </tr>
    
      <tr>
       <td> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="input Three"/> <input type="button" class="remover" value="remove" />
        </td> </tr>
    
    </table>
```