# Can I use for loop with onclick to write out multiple results?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my English.
A want to write out numbers (0, 3, 6, 9... 27) with the help of a for loop, but it seems it is harder than I thought. Thank You for your help.
I found a similar problem: [For loop onclick button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273984/for-loop-onclick-button)

```js
function count() {
  var i = 0;
  if (i < 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (i * 3);

  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "nothing";
  }
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <h1 onclick="count()"><span>Click on me</span></h1> 
  <br/>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Szsolt23/0Lp30amn/)

Comment: Did you want to add 3 every time the `<h1>` gets clicked? If so, you're not looking for a `for` loop.

Comment: I tried first with for loop, but didn't worked. This code is not correct for the title

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I don't think you need a `for` loop.
Your current code defines `i=0` each time the function is called.
You'll just need to define the `i` variable outside of your function so it can be properly incremented.

```js
var i = 0;

function count() {
  if (i < 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (i * 3);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "nothing";
  }
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <h1 onclick="count()"><span>Click on me</span></h1> 
  <br/>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, increment the counter by three upon each click. Below, I'm using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's saying, "if `i` is less than 27, add three. otherwise, set it to 'nothing'."

```js
var i = 0,
    output = document.getElementById('output');

function increment() {
  i = i < 27 ? i + 3 : 'nothing';
  output.innerHTML = i;
}

document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', increment);
```

```html
<h1 id="trigger">Click on me</h1> 
<p id="output">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that:

```
function count() {
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (i * 3)
  }
}
```