# Rails 3 best_in_place_if how to add "id" attribute to element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place_if for inline editing. Here I want to catch the id of current element edited by using the ajax success event of best_in_place.

Below is code snippet I am trying to add id attribute. But when I inspect the html, the value for id attribute is the default value generated by the bes_in_place. As per their doc, its mentioned that the default value can be changed by providing our own value.

The default value for id attribute is shown as id="best_in_place_trip_32_is_active" and I want is only id=32

```
best_in_place_if(current_user.admin,trip,:is_active, :type => :checkbox, :classes => 'trip_disable', :id => trip.id)
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Not sure I can answer this question but can probably help you solve your problem since I use best_in_place heavily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not try to use a numeric-only ID attribute for the element, this [violates the HTML specs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987693/1544012).

Then, to access the `id` of the currently edited record in the success callback, you can **add the record `id` to the data attribute** instead. Something like this should work:

```
# adding the record ID to the data attribute
best_in_place_if(current_user.admin, trip, :is_active, :as => :checkbox, :class => 'trip_disable', :data => { :id => trip.id })

# accessing the record ID in the success calback
$('.best_in_place.trip_disable').bind("ajax:success", 
                         function(){ 
                            alert('Record ID is '+$(this).data('id')); 
                         });
```

See the [Best in place docs](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/tree/v3.0.0#providing-data-to-the-callback) for more info.